# Vector with pointers to Different methods

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to collect pointers to different methods in my vector (properly map):

`std::map < sf::Keyboard::Key, std::function<void()> > keyData;`

and now, when i want to add something to this vector, i have got problem.

```
inputManager.addKeyToCheck(sf::Keyboard::A, std::bind(&mv::Scene::moveViewLeft, mv::Scene::getInstance()));
```

because there I get this error:

> Error  C2665   'std::tuple::tuple': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

I need to storage pointers to methods of different classes and i don't know how i get do it. Any other solutions or ideas how can i repair this code?

Comment: Would a lambda work? e.g. `inputManager.addKeyToCheck(sf::Keyboard::A, []() { mv::Scene::getInstance().moveViewLeft(); }`

Comment: thanks for help! It works!

Answer (score 2):

Prefer lambdas over `std::bind`; they make life much easier:

```
inputManager.addKeyToCheck(sf::Keyboard::A, []() {
    mv::Scene::getInstance().moveViewLeft();
});
```